# What time would shrink the thread pool Tomcat？

Tags: tomcat

Like this:

[image]

The Tomcat version is **7.0.54**, `maxThreads` is 3000,`minSpareThreads` is 800,protocol is `Http11AprProtocol`,the pool increased to 3000 when it was busy but not come down even very idle.

I want to konw if Tomcat never shrink the thread pool? If not,what is mechanism?

Comment: I used to encounter similar issue on my previous job. The only solution was to restart tomcat at some predefined interval.. :(

Comment: Why are you using "keep alive"s. Aren't they preventing the connections from closing? In a pool they should be shared among all requests.

Comment: I got the same result(I answered myself) without the `Keep-Alive`.

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests on my own and my conclusion is that it seems to be relationship with the current QPS and the [`maxIdleTime`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/executor.html) parameter.

For example:

- maxIdleTime=30sec,RPS=10,the threads will reduce to 30*10=300
- maxIdleTime=30sec,RPS=5,the threads will reduce to 30*5=150
- maxIdleTime=30sec,RPS=1,the threads will reduce to 30*1=30

...

And so on,util the number of active threads are less or equal to minSpareThreads